# Should arXiv paper be linked when submitting to a IEEE journal

Tags: arxiv, ieee

IEEE allows submitting papers which have already been published in preprint servers like arXiv. But when submitting, should I link the arXiv paper to the submission?

If I don't do that, would IEEE flag this as plagiarism?
If I have to do that, where to do that? I couldn't find any place to link it when submitting a paper.

Comment: Do the submission and the ArXiv preprint have the same authors?   If so, it is not plagiarism, since ArXiv is not a journal.

Comment: ArXiv cannot be used in a way that creates self-plagiarism.

Comment: Yes, authors, title, everything is the same. Thanks!

Comment: Are you writing a cover letter?

Comment: No. Not writing a cover letter.